# Azure B2C - what is nca when requesting tokens?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When making a post request to ie

```
https://.b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_ROPC_Auth/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

What does nca=1 do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When AAD B2C does a Local Account credential check using the login-noninteractive technical profile, it actually makes an ROPC call to the Azure AD token endpoint. Nca=1 forces Azure AD to lookup the account via the signInNames attribute, rather than the userPrincipalName (default identifier for AAD).

In your example, you’re using the B2C token endpoint (contains a B2C policy id), it doesn’t do anything but create a new request to the AAD token endpoint using login-noninteractive technical profile. So adding it there does nothing.

User/App -> B2C /token -> AAD /token (nca=1)

Comment: Good question! It's mentioned in this sample - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin. It says "At Sign In, the Username provided is used as a lookup against all SignInNames that are present on user objects stored in the the directory. This is achieved by sending the paramater nca=1 when making the authentication request via the login-NonInteractive technical profile in TrustFrameworkBase."

Comment: @rbrayb Thank you! So speaking in terms of performance, I'm guessing it's the preferred way? Are there any scenarios when you don't want to set nca=1? I'm basically building according to this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: You only use it for username (as opposed to email address). I don't think performance comes into it.

Comment: You do not use nca param when interacting with B2C endpoint. You only use nca param with AAD /token endpoint. It is not in the B2C doc because it doesn't do anything there. B2C token endpoint call contains a policyId, AAD token endpoint does not contain a policyId.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Ok that makes sense. So interacting with B2C endpoint doesn't matter if I use it with username vs email address?